# javascript: String to Byte[] to String

Tags: java, javascript, string, arrays

I coded my application in java in a first time and I should now coded it in javascript and I have some problems in the handling of string and arraybytes in javascript and recoding methods of conversion in both directions.
Here is my java code:

```
    public String VerifyPIN(String PIN, String successCb, String errorCb)   {
        byte[] AID = new byte[] {(byte)0xA0,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x10,(byte)0x10,(byte)0x11};
        byte[] tmpPIN = new byte[] {(byte)0x00, (byte)0x20, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x08, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00};
        System.arraycopy(PIN.getBytes(), 0, tmpPIN, 5, PIN.getBytes().length);

        byte[] output = exchange(AID, tmpPIN);
        String result = StringUtils.bytesToString(output);

        if ("90 00".equals(result.trim())) {
            //onSuccess()
        } else {
            //onError
        }

        return result.trim();
    }

    public String bytesToString(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (byte b : bytes) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02x ", b & 0xFF));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        else {
            return "N/A";
        }

    }
```

So how can I convert these two methods *bytesToString* and *VerifyPIN* to javascript.

thank you in advance

Comment: Riahi - SO it not a "write my code for free" service.  We will help you with problems you encounter in doing your own programming, but we won't do your job for you.

Comment: @StephenC: let's wait some minute, some haxxor will

Comment: @AndreaLigios - No. Lets not wait a minute.  This is NOT how SO should be used.

Comment: @StephenC: -1 for not getting sarcasm

Comment: @AndreaLigios: -1 for expecting people to read your tone of voice from ASCII text.  -1 for not using the normal smiley convention to indicate "humour".

Comment: Ok @StephenC, then +1 for living in Australia, and that's all folks :D

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
function string2Bin(str) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return result;
}

function bin2String(array) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, array);
}

string2Bin('foo'); // [102, 111, 111]
bin2String(string2Bin('foo')) === 'foo'; // true
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For the second method, here is the conversion:

```
function bytesToString(bytes) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bytes[i], 2));
  }
  return result;
}
```